# NSObject class for fetching data from sqlite DB is returning null via NSmutuable to UItableview class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

i want to access data fetched in DBhelper class from database in UIViewcontroller class, i have imported class,created object, methods and all variable are accessible in UIViewcontroller class. when methods are called through uiviewcontroller class they are showing database results or whatever methods are assigned to do but when in use those variables/arrays in uiviewcontroller by objects they return null.even i have implemented prperties and synthesised them too.. here is my code

```
-(NSMutableArray *) SaveDBInArray {

    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    [self initializeDatabase];

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM table11";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &init_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        //NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));   }
    while (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
          colum1= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement,0)];
        colum2= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement,1)];
        allEnteries=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         [allEnteries addObject:colum1];
        [allEnteries addObject:colum2]; 
       }
    NSLog(@"array with values %@",allEnteries );
//HERE WHENEVER METHOD IS BEING CALLED IT IS DISPLAYING ONLY TOP ONE VALUE FROM EACH COLUM BUT I WANT ALL OF THEM

    sqlite3_reset(init_statement);
    [self closeDatabase];
    return allEnteries;
}
```

Comment: may i know which part u have edited bro? btw thanks for improving it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your DBhelper class code...

u are initialising array again and again u should use below code

```
\\Initialize array here
 yourtableviewclass*yourclass= [yourtableviewclassalloc]init];
 dbH.allEnteries=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 \\\\\\\ you must create property of allEnteries array in yourtableviewclassclass and 
 synhtesize it. and then try to access that array with following 2 line code in ur    tableview class
 yourtableviewclass *obj = [yourtableviewclass alloc]init ];
 nslog("%@"obj.yourtableviewclass );


 while (sqlite3_step(init_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
      colum1= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char     *)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement,0)];
    colum2= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(init_statement,1)];

     [yourclass.allEnteries addObject:colum1];
    [yourclass.allEnteries addObject:colum2]; 
   }
```

Yourtableviewclas.h code
    @interface Yourtableviewclas: uiviewcontroller{
     nsmutablearray *allEnteries ;
    }
    @property (nonatimic )nsmutablearray allEnteries 
    @end

Yourtableviewclas.m code

```
synthesize allEnteries ;
-(void)viewdidload{
yourtableviewclass *obj = [yourtableviewclass alloc]init ];
 nslog("%@"obj.allEnteries );
}
```

Comment: [thanks alloc]initWitLove]xD..it showed all values of database table in array but another problem is, when i call this array in uitable view class it returns null, even i have implemented property of nsmutuable array , can you help on this please?

Comment: objDBhelper=[[DBhelper alloc]init];
    
    NSLog(@"this is table class %@",objDBhelper.allEnteries);
    [super viewDidLoad];
in viewcontroller i called viewdidload function

Comment: if m not wrong i think DBhelper  is another class and the code u wrote in question is in different class.so if its correct then use updated answer

Comment: and dont initialize allEnteries array in DBhelper class

Comment: no no old one was fine, code in question is in dbhelper class, i want to fetch data stored in array declared in dbhelper class to table class...
look, 3 classes, A,B,C
A=viewcontroller
B=Dbhelper, to fetch update insert data in database and to store it in array allEntries
C=uitableview class, where i have to use that array to show it in a table view
problem is , array shows null when i call it in C (table) class

Comment: then you should do folowing.. declare allEnteries and craete poperty in tableview class synthesize it in use yourtableviewclas *class = [yourtableviewclas  alloc]init]; [class .allEnteries addObject:colum1];
    [class .allEnteries addObject:colum2];

Comment: Done,, thanks mate .. that was really awsome :) this wa my first question here and am glad some one really helped me

Comment: i did it before this conversation in comment box  but it requires 15 reputation to do so, sorry for that mate.. tell me how to get 15 reputation then this answer will be my first vote up :)

Comment: ask 2-3 more question and answer 1-2 questions.